# What is the file permission code to give all users the rights to read, write & execute on a folder

Tags: file, file-permissions

can someone please tell me what is the permission code to give everyone literally everyone the permission to read, write & execute files on my server. The reason I am doing this is just for testing purposes so don't scream at me in the comment section for security and stuff. So all I want to know is the permission code for this like there is also 0755 which only gives permission to the owner to read, write, & execute the files is there any permission code which allows anyone to read, write, & execute the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

777. It's an Octal representation of the binary yes/no permissions (read, write, execute) with each digit representing respectively Owner/User, Group and World/Other.

http://permissions-calculator.org/decode/0755/

http://permissions-calculator.org/decode/0777/

Comment: so will it give the read, write, execute authority to everyone?

Comment: World is the term used for all users /  processes. That is to say everything that isn't the same UID as the owner and isn't the same group.

Comment: @TRT1948 OK awesome, I got it, also one last thing can you please tell me what does the code 666 mean? because I am kinda confusing it with 777 both do the same thing right?

Comment: No. Not the same at all. Well, the same for Read and Write, not eXecute.

Use the permissions-calculator links supplied to investigate that. Octal 6 comes from Octal 4 (read) + Octal 2 (write).  If you want eXecute permission as well, add Octal 1 (execute) to get 7 - this is where the 7 in your 755 and my 777 comes from. The 5 in your 755 comes from Read (4) + eXecute (1). 4 + 1 = 5. Octal because 3 bits are required, one for Read, one for Write, one for eXecute, meaning 8 possible combinations of settings for each of the User, Group and Others (Owner, Group and World).

Comment: I see in your question you say "0755 which only gives permission to the owner". This is not correct - not ONLY the owner, you are also assigning permissions to Group and World/Other with this value - read and execute (no write).